# How to get average of some variable with different initial condition

Tags: list-manipulation

From two different initial condition of theta and r we generate `fxy[{θ_,r_}]` which gives two list of data set for each initial condition.

We get (θ1, r1) and for second set of initial condition we get (θ2, r2). I want to take the average of the first element of what we get from the first initial condition and the first element of the second set of initial condition and go on for second element of both list.

```
n = 500; nr = 40;
θ1 = 0; θ2 = N@π/2;
rmax = N[2 π]; T = 1; w0 = 10;

With[{Kx1 = 0.1}, 
 fxy[{θ_, r_}] := {Mod[θ + r - Kx1 Sin[θ], 2 π], Mod[r - Kx1 Sin[θ], 2 π]}]
 {datax, datay} = Transpose[
   Catenate[
    Table[
     Join[
      NestList[fxy, {θ1, i rmax/nr}, n],
      NestList[fxy, {θ2, i rmax/nr}, n]
      ],
     {i, 1, nr}
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly. You have 2 lists and want to take the (arithmetic) average of both first elements. Then of second elements. e.t.c. This can be done by: `(datax + datay)/2`

Comment: second element of both lists third element of both lists averages also.

Comment: Is this not what I wrote?

Comment: X={1,2,3,4,5}, Y={3,2,8,7,6}, Z={2,9,7,6,5} for three data list .I want to add (1+3+2)/3 for 1 st element and similarly for all data sets.

Comment: Well: (X+Y+Z)/3 will give a list with the results

Comment: I want to change initial value of I and \theta for 50 different set to get (datax,datay) for 50 set then take average.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133594/discussion-between-user68207-and-daniel-huber).